# What does BO1IE8_v1;ENUS indicate in UserAgent?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, user-agent

I have a client who gets browser script errors with our application.  In troubleshooting, I see that the User Agent reported contains a couple of entries I don't recognize:

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; BO1IE8_v1;ENUS)
```

Specifically, what does **BO1IE8_v1;ENUS** indicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Internet Explorer 8.
Personally, I encourage users of IE8 to either upgrade to IE9 or Firefox 15.
IE8 has many, many rendering problems and security risks.

Comment: Accepting on "This is Internet Explorer 8."   Unfortunately, we have right around zero control on what browsers our corporate clients use.  And many of them are still on IE7.